# variance decreases when x gets farther from the average x?

Tags: regression, variance, residuals, leverage

I just read the description of Studentized residual on [Wikipeida.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_residual)

I'm confused about what it says about variance, it says that

> "the residuals, unlike the errors, do not all have the same variance
>   the variance decreases as the corresponding x-value gets farther from
>   the average x-value"

how come?
I think the variance depends on the input data, for example, $Height=20+10*age$ and age input value is from 1 to 10 and I have two same input which are at age 5 their heights are the same, so the variance at age 5 is 0, then I have many different output at age 10, so the variance is obviously greater than 0, how can we say the "variance decreases when $x$ gets farther from the average $x$-value?

Comment: There is some indication, in the way this question is phrased, that it might be predicated on a confusion between statements about the *data* with statements about the *random variables* that represent them in the regression model.  The Wikipedia article is referring to the variance of a set of random variables (the "residuals", denoted $\hat\varepsilon_i$) rather than a second-order description (also called "variance") of the differences between the data responses and their fit (which are also called "residuals").

Answer (score 2):

This relates to the concept of [Leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)). Since in typical regression we are usually minimizing the error of the fit to the data, the "high leverage" values get more weight in this calculation (a minimization problem). For SLR, these high-leverage points are the outliers or points far away from the mean, so the line will tend to be forced closer to these points than to points closer to the mean (which have less influence on the total fitting error). Thus, we'd expect points far from the mean to be closer to the line than the interior points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the variance doesn't necessarily need to decrease when x gets farther from the average x-value according to the definition of variance?

Comment: The definition of variance is not involved here, its HOW the line is fitted to the data. Variance is variance, but the observed residual is a function of not just the variability of the data about the TRUE line, but also the variability of the FITTED line itself...this extra bit makes the residuals have different variances, even though the underlying variability of each point about the true line may be the same...its due to the need to minimize fitted error.